# Remover datos parecidos de una consulta en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas

```
Tabla1
---------------------------------
ID          Año     NOMBRE
---------------------------------
0100730114  2002    EXPERIMENTO 1
0100730114  2003    PRUEBA 2

Tabla2
---------------------------------
ID          Año     NOMBRE
---------------------------------
0100730114  2001    EXPERIMENTO_a 1
0100730114  2003    PRUEBA_a 2
```

lo que quiero obtener es lo siguiente:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tabla1.ID   Tabla2.ID      Tabla1.Año   Tabla2.Año  Tabla1.NOMBRE Tabla2.NOMBRE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
0100730114  0100730114     2002         2001        EXPERIMENTO 1 EXPERIMENTO_a 1
0100730114  0100730114     2003         2003        PRUEBA 2 PRUEBA_a 2
```

Lo estoy intentando con la siguiente consulta

```
select t1.ID, t2.ID, t1.Año, t2.Año, t1.NOMBRE, t2.NOMBRE 
from Tabla1 t1
inner join Tabla2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Pero me devuelve

```
0100730118  0100730118  2002    2001    EXPERIMENTO_a 1 EXPERIMENTO 1
0100730118  0100730118  2002    2003    EXPERIMENTO_a 1 PRUEBA 2
0100730118  0100730118  2003    2001    PRUEBA_a 2  EXPERIMENTO 1
0100730118  0100730118  2003    2003    PRUEBA_a 2  PRUEBA 2
```

he tratado de poner otra condición and con el año pero no me funciona.

```
select t1.ID, t2.ID, t1.Año, t2.Año, t1.NOMBRE, t2.NOMBRE 
from Tabla1 t1
inner join Tabla2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.año = t2.año
```

**Cómo podría realizar la consulta para obtener lo que necesito?**

Comment: Es que los ID son iguales, es un exponente de 2 a la 2.. no hay manera de resolver eso, a no ser que añadas un campo más que se llame "tipo" y lo relaciones por tipo, porque por ID no lo vas a resolver jamás.

Answer (score 3):

Para agrupar los campos que tengan los mismos nombres podrias usar la funcion group by.
prueba con :

```
select t1.ID, t2.ID, t1.Año, t2.Año, t1.NOMBRE, t2.NOMBRE 
from Tabla1 t1
inner join Tabla2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
group by t1.NOMBRE
```

Answer (score 2):

Pareciera que el patrón que relaciona las filas es el nombre quitando el texto `_a` que tienen alguno de los nombres:

```
select t1.ID, 
       t2.ID, 
       t1.Año, 
       t2.Año, 
       t1.NOMBRE, 
       t2.NOMBRE 
       from Tabla1 t1
       inner join Tabla2 t2 
          on t1.ID = t2.ID
          and t1.NOMBRE = REPLACE(t2.NOMBRE, '_a', '')
```

No esta demás decir que es un criterio peligrosamente ambiguo.

Comment: Si, aunque lo que estoy buscando es tratar de relacionar por año, pero lo raro es que la consultad no me devuelve nada, deberia devolverme por lo menos 1 registro `0100730118  0100730118  2003    2003    PRUEBA_a 2  PRUEBA 2` pero queda en blanco, edite la pregunta con la consulta con año

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar buscar parecidos en la columna Nombre pero tendras que examinar los resultados a ver si te valen, porque puede que te funcione o puede que no.

```
select t1.ID, t2.ID, t1.Año, t2.Año, t1.NOMBRE, t2.NOMBRE 
from Tabla1 t1
inner join Tabla2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
and UPPER(LEFT(t1.Nombre,5))=UPPER(LEFT(t2.Nombre,5))
```